# mouseover на тач экранах

Tags: javascript, html, touch-event

Нужно узнать, какой элемент находится под пальцем во время скольжения. 
Делаю:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
  console.dir(e.target);
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

console.dir бесконечно плюёт первый элемент, над которым я был во время старта. Следующие не показывает. 
Сразу скажу, что можно реализовать путем поиска элемента по координатам, но может есть более элегантный способ?

Answer (score 0):

Все дело в том, что в e.target события touchmove пишется элемент, над которым началось событие. Чтобы получить текущий элемент (над которым проходит событие в данный момент) можно использовать document.elementFromPoint:

```
document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
```